# Peripendicular Line at distance d from point in a given direction

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, vectors

I have a line given by $Ax + By + C= 0$, and a point $x_0,y_0$. From that point $x_0,y_0$ in the direction of the line up to distance $d$, I want to find the equation of the line that is perpendicular to the line $Ax + By + C= 0$.
It represented in the figure below.

[image]

I want to find the equation of line $M$. Sorry if the equation seems naive, I don't have much idea about geometry.

I can easily get the slope of other line and represent it as $Bx-Ay+D=0$. The problem is figuring out the value of $D$. I am really looking for a shorthand/direct formula to compute $D$.

Comment: hint: find the coordinates of a point on the given line that lies above point $(x_0, y_0)$ at a distance of $d$.

Comment: @JohnJoy Can  you please elucidate more  on your approach.  I am looking for direct/shorthand formula for computing the equation of the line.

Comment: I realize that you're just looking for a formula, Memorizing formulas is just a really bad way of learning math, though. It's not even math..it's merely mathematical gossip. My approach is to use the Pythagorean theorem to find the point of intersection (the distance between the 2 points is $d$), and use that information along with the slope to find the line (you've already stated that you "easily get the slope of other line").

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if i understood. Do you need the lines that are perpendicular to the one given, and whose distance from X0, Y0 is d?

Edit:
You could calculate the unit director vector from Ax+By+C=0. The director vector would be (-B,A) if I am not wrong, and from it you could calculate the unit vector and multiply it by d (there are two unit directors, choose the one whose second coordinate is positive so that you get the line you are looking for). Let's call it U. Then, if (a,b)=(X0,Y0)+U, (a,b) would be a point that belongs to the line you need. Then, since you know it satisfies the ecuation Bx-Ay+D=0, you could get D from it. I hope it makes sense. New in the site!

Edit 2:
Consider the line BX-AY+D=0. You know B and A, and you need D. Since you know the distance from this line to the point (X0,Y0) is d, you could get D from the distance formula
d=|BX0-AY0+D|/sqrt (A^2+B^2). You will get 2 values for D. One is for the line you are looking for, the other one is for the other line

Edit 3: "proof"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgFvj.jpg

Comment: Yes, exactly. But why do you say lines? There would be only one line. Isn't it?

Comment: As i understood, you would have two lines, with a distance of 2D between them. I'm thinking how i would do it..

Comment: thanks for the reply! In my case, I am only interested in the one whose point of intersection with $Ax+By+C=0$ has a greater y co-ordinate than $y_0$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In respect to Edit 2, since I am writing a simulation code, how can I identify which value of $D$ is correct amongst the two. Given that the line $M$ lies on the positive Y axis side of $Ax+By+C=0$

Comment: The value of D "moves" your line up and down. Use the bigger one

Comment: @Gj_Rk Great! Your answer is exactly what I wanted. Can you please explain more on how you got `D from the distance formula`. The distance formula gives the distance from the line. How does it relate $D$ in the line equation? This would be helpful in understanding your solution better for me. Thanks again!

Comment: EDIT: BX-AY+D=0. From there, (B/A)X+D/A=Y. D/A moves your line up or down.

Comment: Need a proof of the formula?

Comment: Please don't use answers to make comments. (_E.g._, the first line/original revision of this answer.) Once you have [enough reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) you will be able to comment on any post.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).